# Identical members roles on all sites in a multisite

Tags: multisite, user-roles, members

In a multisite system I need editorial accounts with custom rights. Therefore I have chosen the [members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) plugin. As I do have lots of sites, creating and synching the roles for all sites becomes quite tedious.

a) is it possible to manage my roles for all sites globally (network-wise)?
b) would you suggest to use a different plugin?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use Members to do exactly what you want. I use WP eBooks' "Network Roles" in tandem with Members to accomplish what you want: http://wpebooks.com/network-roles/

Comment: Thx. Haven't bought it (yet), but will give you an update, when I've done so.

Answer (score 0):

[User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/) has Multisite capability.

[image: user role manager multisite]

And from the changelog:

> 3.6 = 30.04.2012
>   - WordPress multi-site: when new blog created default role setting is copied for it from the main blog default role value now.
>
> 3.5 = 19.02.2012
>   - User Role Editor could be available now for single site administrators (Administrator role) under multi-site environment. You should define URE_ENABLE_SIMPLE_ADMIN_FOR_MULTISITE constant in your blog wp-config.php file for that. Insert this line “define(‘URE_ENABLE_SIMPLE_ADMIN_FOR_MULTISITE’, 1);” there, if you decide to give single site admin such opportunity.
>
> 3.2 = 25.07.2011
>   - If you run multi-site WordPress network, User Role Editor will automatically duplicate all roles from the main blog (blog with mininal ID) to every new created blog.